# Multiple Contents in SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, html, variables, sweetalert, inputbox

I am wondering if there is a way to put multiple `content: "input",` lines inside SweetAlert.

I will need a way to assign each of these input boxes a name in the `.then` statement.

I am using the latest version of [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)
Please Help!